# How to avoid some pages from being indexed by search engines?

Tags: php, seo, search-engine

There is `rel="nofollow"` but I am not sure about this if it prevents indexing. What do you say? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Sorry I wasn't very clear. There a page a.php, and it has links `b.php`, `c.php`, `d.php` and some other text content. The link to b.php is only relevant if the users are on `a.php`, and doesn't really returns any output. Its not relevant if somebody goes directly on this b.php from yahoo/google search results.

Answer (score 4):

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Comment: hi the pages I want to avoid, dont output any content, pls check question update. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can update the robots.txt file specifying which URLS not to index or make sure that they are not in your sitemap.xml file

http://www.robotstxt.org/